# Find an arc length parametrization of $\langle2t^2,2t^3\rangle$

Tags: calculus, parametrization, arc-length

$r(t) =  <2t^2 , 2t^3 >$

Hello everyone, I have been working on this problem for sometime now. I completed the integration (unless I have messed up along the way), but here is what I have now. I am having trouble completing the problem and have been stumped for some time.

$$t = \pm \sqrt(6) * \sqrt{(18s+8)^{2/3}-4}$$

Comment: i edited the post to fix up your $\LaTeX$; note my use of the braces "$\{$" and "$\}$".  Also "\pm" for $\pm$ etc.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You should show all your work so responders can find your errors. You seem to have made a couple of mistakes. I get
$$\vec r=\langle 2t^2,2t^3\rangle$$
$$d\vec r=\langle 4t,6t^2\rangle dt$$
$$ds=\left|\left|d\vec r\right|\right|=\sqrt{16t^2+36t^4}dt=2t\sqrt{4+9t^2}dt$$
$$s=\int ds=\int2t\sqrt{4+9t^2}dt=\frac2{27}\left(4+9t^2\right)^{3/2}+C=\frac2{27}\left(4+9t^2\right)^{3/2}-\frac{16}{27}$$
If we assume the starting point is at $t=0$. Solving for $t$, I get
$$t=\frac{\text{sgn}\,s}3\sqrt{\left(\frac{27}2s+8\right)^{2/3}-4}$$
Where
$$\text{sgn}\,s=\left.\begin{array}{rl}-1,&s<0\\
1,&s\ge0\end{array}\right\}$$
I checked by inserting back into the expression for $\vec r$ and differentiating. Where was your mistake?

Comment: It was an algebra mistake I made near the beginning of the problem. Thank you very much for helping me out.

Comment: I'm sorry, but where did you get the $9t^2$ from?

Comment: Oops never mind, I see what you did now.

Comment: So I made it up to where you completed the integration. I got a little lost as to where the $-16/27$ had come from.

Comment: Never mind, figured it out again haha.